# QTP/UFT - Storing Multiple Arrays In An Array

Tags: vbscript, qtp, hp-uft

I have a function that imports a sheet to the global sheet and then loops through the columns and rows to create an array.

***Code***

```
Public Function importArray()

    DataTable.ImportSheet "location","Lists", "Global"

    rowCount = DataTable.GetSheet(dtGlobalSheet).GetRowCount -1
    columnCount = DataTable.GetSheet(dtGlobalSheet).GetParameterCount

    ReDim myArray(-1)  

    For x = 1 to columnCount Step 1

        For i = 0 to rowCount Step 1

            ReDim Preserve myArray(UBound(myArray) + 1)
            myArray(i) = Datatable.Value(x, dtGlobalSheet)      
            Datatable.SetNextRow

        Next

        MsgBox Join(myArray, vbNewLine)

    Next

End Function
```

So now that I know I can get the columns into an array, I need to store each array individually.

**For example:**

*Main array = myArray(i)*

*Call importArray() to get array*

*Column count = 2*

*Column names = Name, Surname*

*Store array into array variable with name as column name*

*Populate myArray() with stored arrays*

*myArray(Name(), Surname())*

The reason I want to do this is because I have a function that will need to reference these arrays to look for a value in the array then do some logic. While I know that I can just create arrays one by one, the problem is that I might have 20 arrays to use, in which case the code will become really bulky.

Perhaps there is a better way to do what I am thinking of doing, but otherwise, help on this would be really appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use multidimensional arrays

```
'Declare a Dynamic Array
Dim arrData()

' Make it a multidimensional array
ReDim Preserve arrData(rowCount, colCount)

For Loop row
    For Loop col
       arrData(row, col) = ...
    Next
Next
```

column names as array indexes is not okay - that is a dictionary (Map) already